# How to get mobile device simulator in visual studio to test windows-8 app

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8

Now I am working on a windows-8 app for mobile device.I use visual studio 2012 as my working tool.but there is no simulator for mobile device to test my app on that.The minimum scree size of simulator available is 10.6 inch..how can I get a mobile device simulator on my visual studio to test my app

Answer (score 0):

You can change the resolution of the simulator by using the resolution button on the simulator.  It looks like this:

[image]

This list is limited by the resolutions which your video card supports.

Comment: thank you for your concern.In the available screen size in resolution button 10.6" is the smallest one.I need one screen size less than 5".How can I achieve that..

Comment: @Xav As I noted in my answer, that list is limited by what your graphics card supports.  If it doesn't support a 5" screen, then you can't